# How to recreate the Live Chat Bot?

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-web-app-service, microsoft-teams

How can I make a chat bot like this?

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104381862?src=webduppage&tab=Overview

This bot can be embedded into an html. If you chat with the bot on your website the message gets to your Microsoft Teams Channel and you can reply trough Teams.

Answer (score 0):

At its core, this is just a bot enabled for two Bot Framework channels at the same time - the [Web Chat channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-webchat?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) and the [Microsoft Teams channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/channel-connect-teams?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). (Note that Bot Framework channels are completely different from channels in Teams.)

The Web Channel supports controls designed to be embedded in web pages. Messages posted from the web can then be posted as proactive messages in whatever channels are configured for that purpose.